# Does input redirection (<) append a newline character?

Tags: io-redirection, newlines

I was originally of the impression that

```
$ ./myprog
moo[CTRL-D]
```

is exactly the same as

```
$ echo moo > cow
$ ./myprog < cow
```

But I found that `myprog` always counts one more `\n` in the second version than in the first. Why is this?

Turns out `wc` does the same thing...

```
$ wc -l
moo[CTRL-D]0
```

(Apparently zero lines is possible?)

```
$ echo moo > cow
$ wc -l < cow
1
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` appends a newline, unless you tell it not to, by putting `-n` first or `\c` at the end, or putting `-e` first *and* `\c` at the end or... you really don't want to know all the varieties of echo. Use `printf moo > cow` and you'll have a file with zero lines.

Comment: +1: `printf` is much more portable than `echo`.

Comment: Technically, the only possible *file with zero lines* is empty file. A non-empty file without trailing LF is a file without proper termination of the last line. Could you fix misleading wording in the answer?